# How can I get a square root looking like this?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

How can I get a square root looking like these in LaTeX? Thanks!

[image]

[new picture]

Comment: Can you specify what aspects should be different to `\sqrt{x}`?

Comment: Just `$\sqrt{x}$` ?

Comment: I need the square root to look curly and bold like the one in the picture. I don't know what package I have to use, but inside the square root is also Times (New) Roman font.

Comment: Maybe the answer could be updated. As the 'random guesses' by @samcarter show, no one really has a clear idea what you want. Maybe describe the look that you are rooting for (pun intended), or say what's bad about the standard $sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "curly". To be honest, one doesn't come across this adjective very often when discussing the shape of square-root symbols.

Comment: Or tell use where you got the image from?

Comment: In case you mean that the corner of the root should be rounded, then `mathptmx`

Comment: This square root is bolder than the classic LaTeX square root, it is shrinked and the corner is not that sharp, it's a bit curved.

Comment: @Furfurr Do you have an image of higher quality?

Comment: Yeah.. I'll upload it immediately.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: @Furfurr In case you don't want to wait until someone randomly guessed the correct font, you could  go to http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html and try some fonts.

Comment: Has the image that you have posted been produced with (some variant of) TeX, or by some other means?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

Answer (score 6):

I guess you are looking for the services of the `newtxmath` math font package. Note that if you use it, you should probably also use the companion `newtxtext` text font package. Do check, though, if you want to (or are allowed to) use a Times Roman clone for your document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$\sqrt{x}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've already tried newpxmath, but it's still not curly enough. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Furfurr - OK, I switched the answer to `newtxmath`. Any better? Maybe you should explain what you mean by "curly".

Comment: I’ve got the impression that `$\sqrt{\mathstrut x}$` (with `newtxmath`)  gets closer to the OP’s picture.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti - Thanks. I wish I understood better what "curly" is supposed to mean in the context of square root symbols.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti - Ah, I just noticed that the OP edited the query. I guess he/she means "curved" or "curvy" rather than "curly".

Comment: Yes, the bar of the root is rounded at the edge: I guess this means that the radical has not been produced by TeX’s “Rule 11”, which uses a horizontal rule…

Answer (score 5):

A root sign with round corners:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{x}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I vote this to be the curliest!

Answer (score 3):

If you want more vertical distance between the $x$ and the $\sqrt$ sign then try

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
    \[
    \sqrt{x\vphantom{^2}}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Old one on the right in the image below.

[image]

Comment: I don't need more space in the square root, I need the square root to look curly and bold like the one in the picture. I don't know what package I have to use, but inside the square root is also Times (New) Roman font.

Answer (score 3):

I have used, for `times`, `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}` and `\usepackage{letltxmacro}`(do you want in this mode?).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\makeatletter
\let\oldr@@t\r@@t
\def\r@@t#1#2{%
\setbox0=\hbox{$\oldr@@t#1{#2\,}$}\dimen0=\ht0
\advance\dimen0-0.2\ht0
\setbox2=\hbox{\vrule height\ht0 depth -\dimen0}%
{\box0\lower0.4pt\box2}}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldsqrt}{\sqrt}
\renewcommand*{\sqrt}[2][\ ]{\oldsqrt[#1]{#2} }
\makeatother



\begin{document}
$\sqrt{x} \quad \oldsqrt{x}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have a package that makes the square root curly?

Comment: For my opinion, there are package that makes the square root curly. Sorry.